# DWR Spring-MVC 4.0.5 java based configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dwr

I am trying to include dwr in my project that uses spring mvc 4.0.5. Java based configurations are used in project.
for java based configurations I am using following lines of code in MVCConfiguration.

```
@Bean
    public DwrController dwrController(){
        Map<String,String> configParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
        configParam.put("activeReverseAjaxEnabled","true");

        DwrController dwrController = new DwrController();
        dwrController.setDebug(true);
        dwrController.setConfigParams(configParam);
/*
        AnnotationsConfigurator annotationsConfigurator = new AnnotationsConfigurator();
        annotationsConfigurator.configure();
        dwrController.setConfigurators(configurators);
*/
        List<Configurator> configurators = new ArrayList<Configurator>();
        configurators.add(annotationsConfigurator);
        return dwrController;
    }
    @Bean
    public BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping beanNameUrlHandlerMapping(){
        BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping beanNameUrlHandlerMapping = new BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping();
        return beanNameUrlHandlerMapping;
    }
    @Bean
    public DwrHandlerMapping dwrHandlerMapping(){
        Map<String,String> urlMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        urlMap.put("/dwr/**/*","dwrController");

        DwrHandlerMapping dwrHandlerMapping = new DwrHandlerMapping();
        dwrHandlerMapping.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
        dwrHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);
        return dwrHandlerMapping;
    }
```

WebApplicationInitializer extending class i have added mapping for dwr requests.

```
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/dwr/*");
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
```

But on deployment it shows error stating "The required 'configurators' property should be set".
Can you please suggest if the configuration requires any modifications also how to set the configurators.

**Changed dwrController() method to :**

```
@Bean
    @Autowired
    public DwrController dwrController(BeanFactory beanFactory){
        Map<String,String> configParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
        configParam.put("activeReverseAjaxEnabled","true");

        DwrController dwrController = new DwrController();
        dwrController.setDebug(true);
        dwrController.setConfigParams(configParam);

        AnnotationsConfigurator annotationsConfigurator = new AnnotationsConfigurator();
        SpringContainer springContainer = new SpringContainer();
        springContainer.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        annotationsConfigurator.configure(springContainer);
        List<Configurator> configurators = new ArrayList<Configurator>();
        configurators.add(annotationsConfigurator);
        dwrController.setConfigurators(configurators);
        return dwrController;
    }
```

Now application is getting deployed but for /dwr/engine.js and other requests it is giving error `The requested resource is not available`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the working configuration. Here is my cofiguration class's code

```
    @Bean
    public DwrController dwrController(ApplicationContext applicationContext){

        BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry)applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        Map<String,String> configParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
        configParam.put("activeReverseAjaxEnabled","true");

        ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner scanner = new DwrClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(beanDefinitionRegistry);
        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(RemoteProxy.class));
        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(DataTransferObject.class));
        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(GlobalFilter.class));
        scanner.scan("package.to.scan");

        DwrController dwrController = new DwrController();
        dwrController.setDebug(true);
        dwrController.setConfigParams(configParam);

        SpringConfigurator springConfigurator = new SpringConfigurator();
        List<Configurator> configurators = new ArrayList<Configurator>();
        configurators.add(springConfigurator);
        dwrController.setConfigurators(configurators);


        return dwrController;
    }
    @Bean
    public BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping beanNameUrlHandlerMapping(){
        BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping beanNameUrlHandlerMapping = new BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping();
        return beanNameUrlHandlerMapping;
    }
    @Bean
    public DwrHandlerMapping dwrHandlerMapping(DwrController dwrController){
        Map<String,DwrController> urlMap = new HashMap<String, DwrController>();
        urlMap.put("/dwr/**/*",dwrController);

        DwrHandlerMapping dwrHandlerMapping = new DwrHandlerMapping();
        dwrHandlerMapping.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
        dwrHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);
        return dwrHandlerMapping;
    }
```

Added dispatcher mapping in WebApplicationInitializer implementing class as

```
dispatcher.addMapping("/dwr/*");
dispatcher.addMapping("/");
```

Note :  DwrClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner will skip scan of `@Controller,@Service,@Repository,@Component` so do not use `@RemoteProxy` along with anyone of these spring annotations.

Comment: Can U share your configurations in Java please?

Answer (score 0):

You've created the list but haven't actually set it. Add the following line:

```
dwrController.setConfigurators(configurators);
```

Or even better... do it all in a single line

```
dwrController.setConfigurators(Arrays.asList(new AnnotationsConfigurator()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply lance.
Yes I know, i have commented lines for the same. But annotationsConfigurator.configure(); requires a container object and I dont how t create it.

Comment: lance can i use DwrSpringServlet class when I am using spring MVC in my project and seems like it will also require the configurators to be configured

Comment: Deleted my earlier comments... I don't think you need to call `configure()` explicitly. You only need to provide the AnnotationsConfigurator and DWR should call `configure` (and instantiate the appropriate container).

Comment: Lance removing call to `configure()` deployes the application but it still showing error accessing /dwr/engine.js `The requested resource is not available`. May be something wrong in url mapping|spring security.

Comment: Do you have a `@RequestMapping("/dwr/")` on your handler?